# Prompt error if String input contains Space

Tags: java, string, netbeans, input

I would like to prevent user from including`Space` in a `String` input.

I have tried using a few methods such as:

`(team1Name.contains(" "))`

`(team1Name.matches(".*([ \t]).*"))`

`(team1Name.indexOf(' ') >= 0)` but to no avail.

---

Below is a a snippet of my code and the output:

Code snippet:

```
System.out.print("Name of Team 1: ");
team1Name = sc.next();

if (team1Name.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
    System.err.println("Error");
    System.out.print("Name of Team 1: ");
    team1Name = sc.next();
}

System.out.print(team1Name+ " Goals: ");

while (true) {
    try {
        team1Goals = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        break;
      } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println("Error");
        System.out.print(team1Name+ " Goals: ");
      }
}
```

Output:

```
Name of Team 1: black sheep 
Error 
black Goals: black Goals:
```

---

UPDATE:

Attempt to use `.nextLine()` instead of `.next()`. However, still receive error output:

```
Name of Team 1: black sheep
Error
Error
[] Goals: [] Goals:
```

Placed `[]` to replace the original `Space`/`empty` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner#next()` will not return string with space because space is considered as delimiter, so for input like `black sheep`

- first invocation of `next()` fill return `black`
- and another invocation of `next()` will return `sheep`.

Since result of your second `next()` invocation is used as argument in `Integer.parseInt(...)` you are getting `NumberFormatException` because this method can't parse `sheep`.

Consider instead `next()` using `nextLine()` to read entire string from line.

Comment: Thank you I changed my code to usage of .nextLine() instead of .next(). This time a different situation occured. It did not take in my input with Space, and it still jumps to the next print

Comment: Having some trouble finding this information with my good friend Google. Is the default delimiter for `next()` just an empty space?

Comment: I suspect that you used `nextInt()` or other form of `nextXXX()` method before `nextLine()`. You can find solution for this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint

Comment: @DrewKennedy No, space is not the only delimiter. If you will print `System.out.println(new Scanner("").delimiter());` you will see that its delimiter is regex `\p{javaWhitespace}+` so it uses one or more whitespaces (as whitespace we can also treat `\n` `\r` `\t` and few other characters).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use the next method of Scanner, which only takes the first token, in this case: black. This obviously does not contain a space.
If you want the entire input, use nextLine()

Comment: Thank you I changed my code to usage of `.nextLine()` instead of `.next()`. This time a different situation occured. It did not take in my input with `Space`, and it still jumps to the next print